# AWS Lambda and version upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I have an ApiGateway with an attached Lambda.
Now I want to update a new version for that lambda (upload new code for it).
While uploading/deploying,  what about all the incoming requests ? are they being dropped?

**Question:**

In other words, How can I upload a new version for the lambda code, while keeping requests from being discarded?

*Logically, I should create a load balancer, with a cloned lambda? and then removing it? Is this a viable solution?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about that, Lambda won't drop you any request generally. That's because Lambda is not an `on-daemon 24/7` process, so it will not keep your connection.

Lambda is a `container-based` serverless service, it means only you have requests coming then Lambda will launch a container in the under-layer for you. When all of the things Lambda was done, it will auto-delete the container.

So, if you deployed a new version of your Lambda function, then the current processing container will not use the new code, it will still running the old one. And after the new function applied, the next request will use the new code.